# How to set all keys of object in Javascript to newValue without mutating (Redux)?

Tags: javascript, redux

## Question In JavaScript Form

I have an object like this:

```js
const obj1 = {key1: value1, key2: value2, key3: value3, ...}
```

To change value of `key1` (can be any key), this is my way:

```
const obj2 = {...obj1, key1: newValue}
```

I want to set all keys to some `newValue`, how to do it without mutation?
Wanted Output:

```js
{key1: newValue, key2: newValue, key3: newValue, ...}
```

---

## Question In Redux Form

I have my `state` like this:

```js
{
  key1: value1,
  key2: value2,
  key3: value3,
  // ...
}
```

To change one value, I am doing like this in my `reducer`:

```js
return {
  ...state,
  [action.key]: action.value
}
```

But how to change value of all the keys if I give some value through my `action.value`? I want my next state like this:

```js
{
  key1: newValue,
  key2: newValue,
  key3: newValue,
  // ...
}
```

Comment: You could loop over the keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop over keys, and create a new object using say `reduce`

```js
const obj = {
  key1: 1,
  key2: 2,
  key3: 3
}

const value = 0;

const updated = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => (acc[key] = value, acc), {})

console.log(obj, updated)
```

Just for fun some proxy magic (do not use for production)

```js
const obj = {
  key1: 1,
  key2: 2,
  key3: 3
}

const value = 0

const updated = { ...new Proxy(obj, {
    keys() {
      return Object.keys(obj)
    },
    get() {
      return value
    }
  })
}

console.log(obj, updated)
```